# Is it possible to have some virtual keyboard in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have 2 section in my application that any section has itself keyboard and it's possible to need comes up 2 keyboard in the same time. Is it possible at all?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

     QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();

     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
     if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

     return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The first row returned from Google by query _qml virtual keyboard_ : [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html)

Comment: @folibis i read these ago and I did not catch what you want to mention?is it not possible or not?